# Does carrying valuable cargo increase odds of being attacked?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Yesterday while playing *No Man's Sky*, I found an oceanic planet that contained a multitude of [Sac Venom](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Sac_Venom). Whenever I scanned for resources nearby, these popped up everywhere as far as my scanners would go.

A Sac Venom's average value on the market goes for ~26k per item, so it was only natural to stock up on as many as I can. Afterwards, I was carrying about 500K worth of inventory and I made my way to my ship to travel to the closest space station.

Moments after I left orbit, my scanners picked up hostiles nearby and turned off my pulse engines. Typically I would shoot them down and continue, but about 12 ships warped into my area and took me out like I was nothing.

When carrying an abundance of valuable resource, do you have greater odds of being attacked or was this merely bad luck?

Comment: It could have just been bad luck and good timing that you encountered them when leaving the planet, but for there to be 12 hostile ships, that seems intentional.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf That is exactly what I was thinking

Comment: The only time I ever get attacked by pirates is after I've fixed a crashed ship's pulse engine but before I make it to the space station to buy parts to repair its shields. :P

Comment: FYI, in case you're unaware it doesn't particularly matter if you're killed as you can just fly back after your grave and pick up all the items you lost.

Comment: based on my experience: it's highly likely that you get attacked if you have anything like gold/emeril/etc. on board. this would leave with you with 2 approaches: either sell the goodies on planet and launch with credits instead of loot _or_ upgrade your ship and kick their bums ;>

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes, I am aware :) However grabbing your loot isn't the hassle - it's repairing the damage techs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to say yes, solely based on the message that you get right before you are attacked.

> "Hostile sub-space scan found valuable cargo."

I haven't tested how often this happens with an empty cargo or anything though, so I can't tell you definitively. It may just be random due to the developers cutting a feature that correlated the likelihood with the value of your cargo, too.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, I've found that having more valuables increases both the chance of pirates coming to attack you and the amount of pirates that do. Recently, before I switched to earning a profit from trading, I found a few planets with Gravitino Balls, and, with my combined 30-slot inventory, harvested as many as I could. I found that the second I got out of the atmosphere, I immediately had four pirates chasing me. I was able to get to the space station just above in time, however this was no coincidence.

I proceeded to test my theory by coming up with different amounts of balls, and, although the time it took for them to appear varied slightly, I found that the amount of pirates depended on the value of the goods you're carrying and the (approximate) time depended on the amount of valuable goods you have in storage.

Due to this, I don't recommend harvesting sac venom or any other valuable trading items for money once you have over 500,000. Buy low and sell high, especially with [dynamic resonators.](http://www.polygon.com/no-mans-sky/2016/8/16/12491760/galactic-trade-market-make-money-guide/)

Comment: To be fair, i've been attacked aswell while not having that much valuable in my inventory. I farmed a ton of gold, went to a space station and sold it all, then on the return trip towards the planet I got scanned and attacked.

Comment: @Lyrion Yep, that can happen too. I've been attacked with nothing in my inventory - having more valuable items purely increases the odds.