# Is it possible for enemy ships to ignore you if you don't have any valuable cargo?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Many times now when I'm getting close to a planet I want to land on, a hostile sub space scan triggers. Every single time enemy ships will spawn and begin attacking me because of "valuable cargo."  I've not once be spared by the scans.

What cargo is considered valuable? If I dont have any of the cargo they want, will they ignore me? Do they only scan items in my ship or both my ship and what I'm carrying? Or is it whenever these scans happen, it always results in a dog fight in space?

Comment: Is this a duplicate question? [Does carrying valuable cargo increase the odds of being attacked?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/282089/145980)

Comment: @MageXy My question is more like "what kind of cargo is considered valuable."  Like are there certain ores or other items that hostiles will scan for and target you if you have it? The possible dupe is more like "does carrying a certain amount of valuable cargo result in an increase chance of enemies scanning and targeting you?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always travel between planets with an empty starship or at least as little cheap cargo as possible and am always getting the same valuable cargo scan. I have worked out that the hostile scan must also scan your exosuit because I always keep my valuable stuff in my exosuit. I don't worry about taking on pirates as since my ship got vy'keen modded with the photon accelerator. Taking on space pirates is won of the best actions of the game but you can avoid them switching to the galaxy mode and use the triangle button to activate home then you can go to the nearest space station and use the teleporter job done.

Comment: The short answer is NO, you will be scanned as valuable as they know whats in your exosuit.